# Hide/Show & Enable/Disable a button ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uikit, hidden

I'm quite new at iOS development and I'm facing some trouble with hiding/showing button in my GUI. Because I need some buttons to appear or disappear and to be enabled or disabled. I followed some great tutorials over the net but can not figure out what is going wrong with my code.

Here is my ViewController.h :

```
/
//  ViewController.h
//  WeddingVideoBooth
//
//  Created by Frédéric Mouza on 15/07/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Frédéric Mouza. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UIButton *but_record;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *but_record;

- (IBAction)but_record:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

and my .m file :

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  WeddingVideoBooth
//
//  Created by Frédéric Mouza on 15/07/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Frédéric Mouza. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize  but_record;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    but_record.hidden=YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)but_record:(UIButton *)sender {
        but_record.enabled=NO;    
}

@end
```

It's very simple and, to understand, I just would like the button to disable when you click on it... Currently, the button remains the same when you click on it. I also tried to hide it using the property "`but_record.hidden=YES`" but nothing worked.

Does somebody have an idea, please ?

Thanks again

Comment: Check whether you connected the IBAction to the IB

Answer (score 0):

Add an `NSLog()` into your `but_record` to see if the IBAction is actually getting called. It sounds like that is not triggering as you probably didn't link them together in your Interface Builder. And as mentioned above take out the `hidden=YES`

Comment: Thank you, you were totally right, it was a problem of link in my Interface Builder. I copied and pasted several button and this one went bad...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just to wrap-up and properly close the question.

It's probably obvious for most of you but when dealing with interface one has to be careful:
if you create a button, link it to the interface, give it properties... and then you copy it Xcode keeps the previous link in the copy and if you create a new link by control+drag in your .h file, the previous link remains and may supersede the new one.

Therefore, to prevent this, you have to remove the existing links from the link tab after you copied a button but before you create a new link.
That worked for me.

Hope this will help,

Fred